# Rails: How to make require reload on every refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've notice that when I include password hashing with `require "digest/sha1"` on top of my model, **every time** I make some change in my app, I have to **restart server** to see changes.

That is kind of annoying and it is slowing down development a lot, especially for beginner like me.

I've seen somewhere that with `require_dependency "digest/sha1"` it should work, but it is not working for me (*saying no file error*).

I'm not sure even where to put `require_dependency` as I haven't found any example.

There should be some way to make it work, as it is quite common problem, maybe I was just looking to wrong places.

Thanks

**EDIT :**

I've came to conclusion that error comes when my Ubuntu machine goes to sleep. After wake up, local server (tried thin and WEBrick) give that error.

**EDIT :**

It has nothing to do with Ubuntu sleep. I had a function named `hash` that was giving errors every time, complaining that it got wrong number of arguments, but that function was never called.

So, I've renamed it to `encrypt` and now it is working, but I'm not 100% sure that it is solution, I have to test is more.

If it will be ok, that would be a strange bug, I will post an answer.

Comment: I have used the md5 instead of sha1 and it never required a reboot to test, are you sure your problem is nowhere else?

Answer (score 0):

In development mode, by default, anything in `app/` or `config/routes.rb` is reloaded between requests. If this is not happening for you, it's probably not caused by the require. It's more likely that you've turned off reloading inadvertently.

I've used `digest/sha1` in many projects before and have never had this problem, usually including it in the User model where it's used.

Can you replicate this problem in a brand new Rails project? Does the problem go away if you remove that line? If so that is very odd.

Comment: I will try on new project and paste everything relevant

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `require "digest/sha1"` all works fine?
Anyway check for  `config.cache_classes = false` in `config/environments/development.rb`